# Android: Jsoup.select("article") not working when get element from html file

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I have a html file from a website:
http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/opinion/interviews/india-is-not-sailing-in-the-same-boat-as-turkey-or-indonesia-raghuram-rajan/articleshow/27797904.cms

I only want to get contents in an "article" element. And I used Jsoup with code below. The statement "eles = doc.select("article");" not return anything. However, when I replace "article" with "title"/"head"/"body", it work fine.

What happens here? Sorry because my english not good!

EDIT: I have uploaded my full code. Please give me a successful example!

main.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="XXXX" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package tvt.jsouptest;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView v;
    TextView tv;
    String tt = "1", er = "2";

    String urlw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        v = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wView);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);

        urlw = "http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/opinion/interviews/india-is-not-sailing-in-the-same-boat-as-turkey-or-indonesia-raghuram-rajan/articleshow/27797904.cms";

        new NewTasks().execute(urlw);

    }

    class NewTasks extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Document> {

        Element eles;

        @Override
        protected Document doInBackground(String... params) {
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                tt = doc.title();
                eles = doc.select("div.artText").first();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                doc = null;
                er = e.toString();
            }

            return doc;
        }

        public void onPostExecute(Document result) {
            if (result != null) {
                try {
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView))
                            .setText("Title: "
                                    + tt
                                    + "\nStart........................................\n"
                                    + eles.toString()
                                    + "\nEnd..........................................");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView))
                            .setText("Error-TRUE: " + e.toString());
                }
            } else {
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView)).setText("Error-FALSE: "
                        + er);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tvt.jsouptest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="tvt.jsouptest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument you have provided in the `select()` method (e.g. "article") specifies a tagname.                `<title>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` are all valid HTML tags and will select some elements. On the other hand, `<article>` is not a valid HTML tag so nothing will be selected. Read up on this [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

If you view the source of that page, you will find that the article text exists in a div that has a class, specifically `<div class="artText"></div>`. So to select that:

```
Element eles = doc.select("div.artText").first();
```

If you want only the text from that Element (remove all the HTML tags), simply use `eles.text()` when setting it as the content of your TextView.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But it's not working for me. I had a NullPointerException at "eles.toString()" (or eles.text()). That means "eles" object is null? What I must do?

Comment: Could you see my code again and give me a example? Please, ashatte! I really don't know why it's not working!

Comment: This does not really answer your question, but to experiment more with jsoup, go here : http://try.jsoup.org/. You can just past the html source code there and try some selector statements to see if they actually work before putting them into your program.

Comment: Oh. Thanks @Rohan. I think my problem is in the html file. I will try and fix it.